# Urgent help with preparing a table

Tags: tables

[image]

I'm writing my internship report and I need to include this Table, I wonder if there is someone who can help with the TeX program for this Tab.

Comment: Have you tried something on your own? did you have a look at, e.g., [the first google answer for the search _latex tables_](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

The table you're looking to replicate has some mildly challenging aspects:

- repeated footnote marks in the table ("c" and "d")
- need to increase row heights because of presence of superscripted stuff
- typesetting scientific number and associated scientific unit
- some math stuff in bold
- the six numerical columns should probably all have equal width, and the
  table should probably span the width of the text block

In the MWE below, the following packages are loaded to address these challenges:

- threeparttable: to typeset a table with a caption, a tabular part, and a footnote part
- bm: to typeset bold math stuff
- tabularx: to typeset a tabular environment with equal-width columns, with a new
  column type of "C" defined to center-set the cells' contents
- siunitx: for consistent typesetting of numerical quantities and their scientific units

Separately, "top" and "bottom" struts are inserted to increase the row heights, and the `\footnotesize` macro is used to force the footnote-area material to be typeset 20% smaller than the main text. I didn't fill in all of the footnote text; I trust you can do that plenty well. :-) You will also still need to choose the caption text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,bm,tabularx,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered-contents column type
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TBstrut}{\Tstrut\Bstrut}       % top&bottom struts
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{xyz}  % supply the real caption at some point
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c*{6}{|C}|}  % set table to occupy full width of text block
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
\multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Required relative uncertainty, \%\TBstrut}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Pressure range}\TBstrut & $\bm{\rho}$ & $\bm{c}$ 
& $\bm{C}_P$ & $\bm{P}^{\textit{sat}}$ 
&  $\bm{\rho}^L$ & $\bm{\rho}^V$ \\
\hline
$P\le \SI{30}{\mega\pascal}\TBstrut$ \tnote{a} &
0.2 \tnote{b} & 1--2 \tnote{c} & 1--2 \tnote{c} & 
0.2 \tnote{d}& 0.2 & 0.4\tnote{d}\tnote{,e}\\
\hline
$P> \SI{30}{\mega\pascal}\TBstrut$ \tnote{f} &
0.5 & 2 & 2 & - & - & - \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Larger uncertainties are to be expected in the extended critical region
\item[b] In the extended critical region, $\Delta P/P$ is used instead of $\Delta\rho/\rho$
\item[c] \dots
\item[d] \dots
\item[e] \dots
\item[f] States at pressures $>\SI{100}{\mega\pascal}$ are not considered due to their limited technical revevance
\end{tablenotes}
\ \ \ Superscripts: \textsuperscript{\emph{sat}} Saturated; ${}^{L}$ Liquid; ${}^{V}$ Vapor.
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's something that illustrates the essentials of what you need to get your table up and running:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Centered text spanning columns} \\\hline
  lines of stuff & content a & content b & content c \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\cline{<col_a>}{<col_b>}` tells LaTeX to draw a horizontal lines spanning columns `a` through to and across column `b`.

The `\multicolumn{<num>}{<format>}{<content>}` tells LaTeX to create a new column that spans `<num>` columns in the style of `<format>` where format is `c`, `l`, `r`, or any other directive.

If you want the footnotes immediately after the table, you can embed the table in a `minipage` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Centered text spanning columns} \\\hline
    lines of stuff & content a\footnote{this is my first footnote} & content b & content c \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding the footnotes, if you do want them immediately following the table and table itself ends in a horizontal line, then you probably want to add the line

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}%%
```

But place that command **inside** the `minipage` or else you'll lose those lines everywhere in your document, which is probably not ideal.

Here I actually redefine `\footnoterule` to be a negative vertical space because, without the rule, there just seems to be too much white space. While `-2ex` is probably a bit excessive, I wanted to make it noticeable here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace{-2ex}}%%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Centered text spanning columns} \\\hline
    lines of stuff & content a\footnote{this is my first footnote} & content b & content c \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i reuse a footnote ?

Comment: @Abdallah I would advise you to consider Mico's answer.

Comment: thank you for your advise will take it into consideration next time.